# CloudWatch Events to AWS Lambda - Cannot read property 'vpc' of undefined

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, vpc

Whenever I test the Lambda function in the console, it executes perfectly. Only when I try to automate the trigger of my lambda function (by creating a new VPC), I receive the Error. Honestly not sure what is wrong and would love some help. Thanks!

Lambda Function:

```js
exports.lambda_handler = async function(event, context, callback) {

  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  const id = event.responseElements.vpc.vpcId;
  const aws_accountid = process.env.aws_accountid;
  const aws_region = process.env.AWS_REGION;
  const logrole = process.env.stack_logrole;
  const logdest_arn = 'arn:aws:logs:' + aws_region + ':' + aws_accountid + ':log-group:/aws/vpc/' + aws_accountid + '/flowlogs:*';
  const logrole_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::' + aws_accountid + ':role/' + logrole;
  const ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15', region: aws_region});
  const params = {
      ResourceIds: [id],
      ResourceType: 'VPC',
      TrafficType: 'ALL',
      LogDestination: logdest_arn,
      DeliverLogsPermissionArn: logrole_arn,
      LogDestinationType: 'cloud-watch-logs'
    };

  ec2.createFlowLogs(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
    });

  callback(null, "Flow Logs were enabled on " + id);

};
```

Error:

```js
{
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'vpc' of undefined",
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "exports.lambda_handler (/var/task/index.js:4:37)"
    ]
}
```

So I enabled logging on the event to see what I was getting from CloudWatch (entire matched event):

```js
responseElements: 
{ requestId: 'accda467-e955-4e39-918e-d6ebc1169679',
vpc: [Object] },
requestID: 'accda467-e955-4e39-918e-d6ebc1169679',
eventID: '9eaba092-e716-4f7d-87b0-f99efc1c376a',
eventType: 'AwsApiCall' } }
```

Event used to test:

```js
{
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "accessKeyId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "sessionContext": {
            "attributes": {
                "mfaAuthenticated": "true",
                "creationDate": "xxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "sessionIssuer": {
                "type": "Role",
                "principalId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/xxxxxxxxxx",
                "accountId": "xxxxxxxx",
                "userName": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            }
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "CreateVpc",
    "awsRegion": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "sourceIPAddress": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "userAgent": "console.ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "requestParameters": {
        "cidrBlock": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "instanceTenancy": "default",
        "amazonProvidedIpv6CidrBlock": false
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "requestId": "38ab2b4b-1707-46b3-84b3-db7209e4d9c7",
        "vpc": {
            "vpcId": "vpc-077xxxxxx",
            "state": "pending",
            "ownerId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cidrBlock": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cidrBlockAssociationSet": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "cidrBlock": "xxxxxxxx",
                        "associationId": "xxxxxxxx",
                        "cidrBlockState": {
                            "state": "associated"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": {},
            "dhcpOptionsId": "xxxxxxxx",
            "instanceTenancy": "default",
            "tagSet": {},
            "isDefault": false
        }
    },
    "requestID": "38ab2b4b-1707-46b3-84b3-db7209e4d9c7",
    "eventID": "b414662e-f651-4c79-8f3f-5158e78cb97c",
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "recipientAccountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

2/5/2019 -- Added JSON

```js
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "555cbe35-15bb-1ae4-d129-19a9d1f0b8cf",
    "detail-type": "AWS API Call via CloudTrail",
    "source": "aws.ec2",
    "account": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "time": "2019-02-05T16:24:44Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "eventVersion": "1.05",
        "userIdentity": {
            "type": "AssumedRole",
            "principalId": "AROAIWDDPATYMGRZHUC5U:xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "accountId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "accessKeyId": "ASIAYTX6VP3NAVVT7NWC",
            "sessionContext": {
                "attributes": {
                    "mfaAuthenticated": "true",
                    "creationDate": "2019-02-05T15:57:11Z"
                },
                "sessionIssuer": {
                    "type": "Role",
                    "principalId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "arn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "accountId": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "userName": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
                }
            }
        },
        "eventTime": "2019-02-05T16:24:44Z",
        "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "eventName": "CreateVpc",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "sourceIPAddress": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "userAgent": "console.ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "requestParameters": {
            "cidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
            "instanceTenancy": "default",
            "amazonProvidedIpv6CidrBlock": false
        },
        "responseElements": {
            "requestId": "c2d2c32f-96bf-4a73-b281-ddcfc47f6163",
            "vpc": {
                "vpcId": "vpc-074fa2axxxxxxx",
                "state": "pending",
                "ownerId": "xxxxxxxx",
                "cidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
                "cidrBlockAssociationSet": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "cidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
                            "associationId": "vpc-cidr-assoc-065xxxxxxxxx",
                            "cidrBlockState": {
                                "state": "associated"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": {},
                "dhcpOptionsId": "dopt-xxxxxx",
                "instanceTenancy": "default",
                "tagSet": {},
                "isDefault": false
            }
        },
        "requestID": "c2d2c32f-96bf-4a73-b281-ddcfc47f6163",
        "eventID": "452fb486-ca5a-423d-b3ae-b0f9664a0adf",
        "eventType": "AwsApiCall"
    }
}
```

Comment: would you mind adding JSON.stringify(event,null,2) at the start of your function ? (just before const AWS for example).  And post the full JSON in your question ? Thanks

Comment: Sure! Please give me a moment add this.

Comment: According to your JSON it would be `event.detail.responseElements.vpc.vpcId`

Comment: That did it. Thank you!